# Google Now Bill Reminder

Tags: google-schemas

My company is looking to have Google Now Bill Reminders from emails to our clients so they are reminded when to pay.

We aren't looking to integrate a separate app or anything, we just want it directly through Google Now/Gmail.

My question is, is there any definitive structure our emails need to be in, or any information we must include for the Google Now reminders to work? Or does the Now card need to be integrated completely in order to work?

Any links etc to documentation regarding the bill reminder feature so we can look into this? Or if it does need to be integrated, are there any links to API integration so we can forward this to a developer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [Google Now](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/google-now) documentation:

> Google Now brings users the right information at just the right time. For example, Google Now already provides updates to restaurant and hotel reservations or flight information received in Gmail. By marking up email notifications to your users, you can use Google Now to bring them similar updates about your services and products.

Be mindful that only some types are supported in Google Now. For example, use [`Event Reservation`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation) type to declare a reservation for one or more guests at an event.

For your case, you can check on this [blog](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/09/19/google-now-bill-reminder-integration-rolling-out-now/) and this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/LvEgfhrmAD8). Basically, Google Now is most useful for its ability to contextualize information from your Calendar and Gmail to send you alerts when you actually need them. Google Now introduced a new feature that makes it easier to keep track of which phone/Internet/education loan bills are actually due. [Source](https://www.fastcompany.com/3036847/internet-of-things/google-now-will-now-remind-you-when-your-bills-are-due).